# Why is this script taking more time in python3 than python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.3

I wrote this script to determine the first triangular number to have more than 500 factors (a project euler problem) and ran it on both python2.7 and python3.3. I expected them to take more or less the same time but python3 take more than twice the time that python2.7 does. What could be the reason behind this?

```
    def highest_power(integer,prime):
        i=0
        while integer%prime**i==0:
            i+=1
        return i-1

    def n_factors(integer):
        number_of_factors=1
        start=2
        while integer>1 and integer>=start:
            number_of_factors=number_of_factors*(highest_power(integer,start)+1)
            integer=integer/start**highest_power(integer,start)
            start+=1
        return number_of_factors

    def main(number_of_factors):
        number_of_factors_list=[1,1] # Initialized with number of factors for m=1 and 2
        m=3
        while number_of_factors_list[-1]*number_of_factors_list[-2]<number_of_factors:
            if m%2!=0:
               number_of_factors_list.append(n_factors(m))
            elif m%2==0:
                number_of_factors_list.append(n_factors(m/2))
            m+=1
       return (m-2)*(m-1)/2

    if __name__=='__main__':
        print(main(500))
```

Here are their timings

```
   $ time python2 script.py
   real 0m12.787s
   user 0m12.788s
   sys  0m0.000s

   $ time python3 script.py
   real 0m27.738s
   user 0m27.739s
   sys  0m0.000s
```

I'm running this on ubuntu 13.10 64 bit, with the precompiled binaries of python2.7 and python3.3.

Comment: Try checking the bytecode using [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html), and see if it's the same in both Python versions.

Comment: I would guess it's because you're using floating point division in python3 and integer division in python2. (e.g. your `integer` variable will be a float in python3) It's probably not the speed of the calculations as much as it is the floating point calculation changes the number of iterations in some of the loops.

Comment: @JoeKington: that was my first thought, too.  So I switched to `//` and still saw a significant difference in runtime, particularly in `highest_power`.  I seem to remember being disappointed in python 3's integer performance (due to the int/long unification, maybe?) but not the details, and I haven't checked it in a while.

Comment: @DSM - Interesting! Maybe it's due to the `int`s in python2 becoming arbitrary-precision regardless of their size in python3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using integer division in Python 2, and floating-point division in Python 3. See if adding

```
from __future__ import division
```

to the script increases the runtime under Python 2.

Comment: That's a better idea, since it keeps the algorithm the same between 2 and 3.

Comment: Yeah, that does increase the runtime for python2 though it still does not take quite as long as python3. Also using `//` instead of `/` reduced the runtime for python3. Though i'm still quite puzzled. Why has python3 suffered performance regressions?

Comment: @Bolt64 Ever found that out? I can vouch for your qualm on this one; I stumbled across the same while doing another project euler problem! My script takes 3x times in python3 as compared to x in python2. https://github.com/arcolife/codeRiddles/blob/master/proj_euler/p7_prime_nth.py